A conditional probability problem about a fiber cabel and bits, Bayes' theorem
I've been racking my brain about this problem for way longer than I should:
"Through a fiber cabel, information is sent in the form of bits, that can take the values 0 or 1. Sometimes, there is noise on the line, so that a sent 0 will with the probability 1/10 during a transmission be changed to 1.
A sent 1 will with the probability 1/5 during transmission be changed to a 0. The probability of a randomly chosen bit being sent with the value 0 is 2/3.
A bit with the value 0 is received.
a) What is the probability that the received bit was sent with the value 0?
A bit with the value 1 is received.
b) What is the probability that the received bit was sent with the value 1?"
I can't even solve problem a. I always end up with one unknown variable no matter what I try.
The problem is intended for senior high schoolers. The formulas intended to be used are among others: conditional probability, Bayes' theorem, law of total probability, probability of union, and probability of complementary event.


If you show your work, you will get more helpful feedback about where you might have made a mistake and what you can do to correct it.

In a sample space of $30$ bits, how many will be sent and received as $0$, how many will be sent and received as $1$, how many will be sent as $0$ and received as $1$, and how many will be sent as $1$ and received as $0$?

Nevermind, I think I solved it. P(M0) = P(M0 | S0) * P(S0) + P(M0 | S1) * P(S1) = (1 - P(M0 | S1)) * P(S0) + P(M0 | S1) * (1 - P(S0))

In a sample space of $30$ bits, $20$ will be sent as $0$ and $10$ will be sent as $1$.
Of the bits sent as $0$, $18$ will be received as $0$.  Of the bits sent as $1$, $2$ will be received as $0$.  Therefore, $18$ of the $20$ bits that are received as $0$ were sent as $0$ so if you receive a $0$, the probability the bit was sent as $0$ is $0.9$.
Of the bits sent as $1$, $8$ will be received as $1$.  Of the bits sent as $0$, $2$ will be received as $1$.  Therefore, $8$ of the $10$ bits received as $1$ were sent as $1$ so if you receive a $1$, the probability the bit was sent as $1$ is $0.8$.
